# Create mysql database using mysql command

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having a problem when trying to create a database using mysql command. The code i am using is;

```
using (MySqlConnection con = connect_db())
{
    con.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE @name;", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "fancydb");

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {                   
        return;
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

When I try to run this code I always get an error saying that I have an

> error in mysql syntax near "fancydb"

but when I put the name in the command like: `"CREATE DATABASE facnydb;"` it works. Can anyone explain to me why is the error only happening when I try and use parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The create-statement is not a data-manipulation-statement. Parameters are only allowed in such kind of operations. The create-statement ist a data-definition-statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that query is executed as

```
CREATE DATABASE "fancydb";
```

which is wrong.

Comment: No! It will execude as `CREATE DATABASE fancydb;`

Answer (score 1):

SqlCommand Parameters are supported for *[Data manipulation language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language)* operations not *[Data definition language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)* operations.

Data manipulation language =

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...
UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Data definition language =

```
CREATE TABLE ... 
DROP TABLE ... ;
ALTER TABLE ... ADD ... INTEGER;
```

Comment: So far the simplest answer I've seen on the topic of what you can and can't do. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
cmd.CommandText = "exec ('CREATE DATABASE ' + @database)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", restoreDB);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```